# calculate zeros of the 6th degree polynomial in Anylogic

Tags: numeric, anylogic, equation-solving

I wanted to solve the following equation in Anylogic:
0=44.00*m^6+7.84*m^4-43.2*m^3+7.84*m^2+1.16

Anylogic have a lot of Numeric tools. Can somebody help me how to use this tools?

Jan

Comment: Hi Jan, welcome to SOF. Unfortunately, this is really not how you ask questions here. Please ask specific questions and show your work, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could use an online calculator to solve it, e.g. [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/equation-calculator/), which will also detail the steps, which may give you sufficient information to construct a solution in AnyLogic.

It solves it [thus](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/equation-calculator/0%3D44.00%5Ccdot%20m%5E%7B6%7D%2B7.84%5Ccdot%20m%5E%7B4%7D-43.2%5Ccdot%20m%5E%7B3%7D%2B7.84%5Ccdot%20m%5E%7B2%7D%2B1.16).